# Is there a way to include Attributes with values (combo) to a customization project?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'd like to include custom attributes (that contain values for selectors), as well as segmented key values to a customization package so that they're installed upon publication - is there any way to do this?

Thanks...

Comment: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/customization-plugin-packages-configuration/

Comment: That's fine - but how does that code get implemented?  Do you write it in C# in Visual Studio as a class library and add to the files menu?  Do you use the code window in the customization manager to write that code?  Lots of context missing.